# When is a sum of various roots of unity a square in a finite field?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

This question comes from finite groups and their representations.

Let $q$ be a power of a prime $p$ and $1\leq a\leq p-1$. Whether $a$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_p$ depends not on $p$ but only on the congruence of $p$ modulo $4a$. On the other hand, if $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_q$ then whether $n$ is a square or not depends only on whether $2n\mid (q-1)$, so again the congruence of $q$ modulo some integer.

Since integers are sums of roots of unity, namely $1$, I am looking at whether there is a generalization of the above situations. Namely, let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity in an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $p$, let $I$ be a multiset of integers, and let $\alpha=\sum_{i\in I} \zeta^i$ be a sum of powers of $\zeta$. If $\alpha$ lies in $\mathbb{F}_q$, then we ask whether $\alpha$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_q$.

So the question is:

Given $n$ and $I$, does there exist some integer $m$ such that, for any two prime powers $q$ and $q'$ with $q\equiv q'\bmod m$, $\alpha$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_q$ if and only if $\alpha$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_{q'}$?

In other words, does $\alpha$ being a square depend on the congruence of $q$ modulo some integer, rather than in some more complicated way?

I think the answer is 'yes', and it involves Galois theory of cyclotomic fields (namely the fact that the Galois groups are abelian), but I'm really not clued up about algebraic number theory.

(This question is a much simplified version of a previous question that I asked earlier today. I deleted that question and started anew because this version is so different to the previous one that an edit wouldn't really help.)

Comment: From class field theory, it should be the case that the question has a positive answer whenever $\sqrt{\alpha}$ lies in some (potentially other) cyclotomic field. Since $\sqrt[4]{1+i}$ does not lie in a cyclotomic field, this is not a vacuous condition.

Comment: It is not immediately clear to me that the answer to the question *whether $\alpha$ is a square in $\Bbb{F}_q$* is independent on the choice of $\zeta$. Basically because in characteristic $p$ disting primitive $n$th roots of unity need not be conjugate to each other over the prime field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen There are significant restrictions on what $\alpha$ can be (because there are restrictions on the possible fields of values for characters of groups, which is where the problem comes from). The only problem is, nobody knows what these restrictions are. One such restriction should be that the answer is independent of choice of primitive root!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Actually, this is even more intriguing than I first thought. I'd never appreciated that this is an actual restriction. (The number $\alpha$ is the discriminant of the unique bilinear form on a vector space that is invariant under an irreducible real representation of some finite group.)

Comment: A simple example of the phenomenon I described. $2$ and $3$ are both primitive fourth roots of unity in $\Bbb{F}_5$. $1+3$ is a square but $1+2$ is not. Easy to construct more because every function from a finite prime field to itself can be written as a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Guaranteeing independence of the choice of $\zeta$ is more difficult. Should $p$ be a generator of $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$ we do achieve independence because the powers of the Frobenius then permute the primitive $n$th roots transitively. But $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$ is cyclic only in the selected few cases that I'm sure you know at least as well as I do.

Comment: (cont'd) Anyway, this observation may (or may not?) point you to an interesting example from the representation theory side. The next case could be to look at $(n,p)$ pairs such that $p$ generates an index two subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$. Then Galois theory gives us independence for one half of the choices of $\zeta$, and we may learn something about the polynomials corresponding to the multiset from the requirement that it should also work for the other half of choices of $\zeta$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So the conclusion of this is, I think, that I cannot simplify my question this far. The reality is that I have an integral element $\alpha$ of a cyclotomic field $\mathbb Q(\zeta)$, and maps from $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$ to $\mathbb F_q$ for some $q$. The question is whether the image $\alpha$ is a square in $\mathbb{F}_q$. This hopefully doesn't depend on the map chosen, although it still might. If it does depend on the map, I think that's very strange, because $\alpha$ is a square in $\mathbb F_q$ iff the subgroup embeds in a $+$-type orthogonal group. This is well defined. Hmm.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The example you gave, of $1+i$, doesn't have a square root in a cyclotomic field in the first place. But I can see your issue, and I'm sure there's a version of the problem with the square root being in a cyclotomic field. I'm still trying to fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128468/discussion-between-david-a-craven-and-jyrki-lahtonen).